# How can a neutrino have same spin as an electron?

Tags: quantum-spin

Is there any explanation or just any guess about how a particle which is about a billion time smaller than an electron can have same vaule of spin: $\hbar$/2?

The spin is an intrinsic property, that means that the mechanism of its origin escapes us, but does that justify the assumption that there is no physical mechanism at the base, and that that is not at all related to the mass of the particle?

Has anyone ever attempted to give a plausible origin, explanation of the phenomenon?

Comment: How are spin and size related?

Comment: @Sanya, usually spin of massive particles is related to mass and size(radius). Does the fact that the experimental value is not matching the usual formula make that value completely arbitrary? Why should particles different in all possible ways have exactly the same magnitude of spin? Doesn't that require an explanation, one was never lookked for or never found? The magnetic moment is an intrinsic property, too, but the neutrino's value is assumed to be 10^10-10^19 times smaller, what makes spin so unique?

Comment: The electron and the neutrino have the same radius: zero. Fundamental particles are treated as being point-like with no size in QFT.

Comment: The neutrino also has the same spin as the quarks and the composite neutron and proton. Spin is quantized in quantum mechanics so radically different particles have identical spins. That's just how nature works.

Answer (score 1):

Spin is unrelated to mass in any sense. What is known from the representation theory of $SU(2)$ group is that it must be a multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: isn't it considered odd/ puzzling *at all* the fact that they have same magnitude of spin? Does the fact that the value is exactly the same suggest a particular reason why spin should be $\hbar$/4$\pi$? Am I the only one to be surprised?

Comment: Spin is **not** unrelated to mass: massless particles can only have two polarisations, while massive ones can have $2j+1$. *Once* we declare the particle to be massive, its actual mass becomes irrelevant to study its spin.

Comment: @tvb I can just repeat that the particle spin is fixed to be a multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$ due to elementary mathematical reasons. Is it surprising that $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @ben Remember one simple fact -- $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}=1$. Thus spin is a multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$. $10^{-10}$ is not a multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I meant $\hbar$/ 2 * 10^10

Comment: @ben Yes, it can be.